# Rating effect on no-show

Tags: rating, fide, elo

In a long time control (90+30) team championship game I showed up on time but wrong city and lost the game - will this affect my rating? I arrived at the wrong location and missed the game.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong city? Can you give more information?

Comment: I arrived at the wrong location and missed the game

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the latest [FIDE rating regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022017) your game was not played and therefore will not be rated. Both players must make at least one move before the game can be rated

> 5. Unplayed Games
>    5.1
>
> Whether these occur because of forfeiture or any other reason, they are not counted. Any game where both players have made at least one move will be rated.